# React-PDF Display Text has different value when Copied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

The highlight Text is from a short SHA from git summit.

This is PDF document generated with React-pdf.
Even though the display text is `4903677`, when copied, it changed to `•G07THH`

The font is D-DINPro.otf

`console.log()` return the correct value.

What is happening here? Text Decode bug?

The Document code is pretty simple

```
<View style={styles.versionControl}>
    <Text>
        { new Date().toISOString()}
        {
            data.sha &&  <>--{data.sha}</>
        }
    </Text>
</View>
```

[image: Display Text has Different Value]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the error from the font package.  When in default, the rendered values are correct.

To fix, I import and export the Free D-Din font from `birdfont` program, this will fix the value issues in React-pdf.

Answer (score 1):

In short, react-pdf uses bfrange for the Unicode mappings. It may cause problems on some pdf viewer like Chrome's built-in viewer. Check this [discussion](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/1950#issuecomment-1721468432) for the details. You can try to implement `bfchar` in the `toUnicodeCmap` method to fix this problem.