# Copying/pasting pdf text gives garbled text after changing the registered font of react-pdf

Tags: fonts, truetype, react-pdf

I was generating pdf files using [react-pdf/renderer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-pdf/renderer). It was using ‘ACaslon Pro’ as the registered font.

Now, I changed the font to Georgia Pro. The generated pdf looks perfect. But when copying/pasting the text, getting some garbled or meaningless text as shown below.

> The proecc rs eforndfi orfgepvc dfsrptmvdrf sprt m crapoe dfvr cutyrbc
>
> srp orttafdomvdrf rp cvrpmiel .eorndfi dc vhe pegepce proeccD orfgepvdfi
>
> orne cutyrbc ymo, dfvr m srpt vhmv vhe peod defv afnepcvmfncD caoh mc
>
> kfibdch rpEmfn / mfdchl

But, there was no issue with the old font.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Font, Page, Text, View, Document, StyleSheet } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

Font.registerHyphenationCallback(word => {
  return [word];
});

// Create styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    padding: 30
  },
  text: {
    fontFamily: 'GeorgiaProLight'
  }
});
// Register a font
// old font
Font.register({
  family: 'ACaslonPro',
  src: 'http://localhost:3000/fonts/ACaslonPro/ACaslonPro-Regular.otf'
});
// new font
Font.register({
  family: 'GeorgiaProLight',
  src: 'http://localhost:3000/fonts/GeorgiaPro/GeorgiaPro-Light.ttf'
});

const test = () => {
  return (
    <Document title="Test" author="xxx" language="en-US" >
      <Page size="LETTER" style={styles.page} wrap>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          The process of encoding converts information from a source into symbols for communication or storage. Decoding is the reverse process, converting code symbols back into a form that the recipient understands, such as English or/and Spanish.
        </Text>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};
```

I installed the Georgia Pro font from [microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/georgia-pro/9n9dzg1xt2mb#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) and located the font files in the following path:

C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.GeorgiaPro*1.0.2.0*neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe

After this, I tried to generate PDFs using Georgia and Times New Roman fonts (Got font files from C:/Windows/Fonts). Those pdf files also have the same issue. They also give the exact garbled text as Georgia Pro on copy/paste.

My pdf-react/renderer version was 1.6.8. Now, I upgraded it to 2.1.1. But no difference.
I fount a similar question in Stack Overflow :
[React-PDF Display Text has different value when Copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585868/react-pdf-display-text-has-different-value-when-copied). I don't have birdfont program installed in my system.
Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the toUnicodeCmap method in pdfkit. Check the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77113708/2891794). In short, you can implement bfchar in the toUnicodeCmap method instead of bfrange. Based on our testing, everything works normally when using bfchar encoding.